# How to change the database for the meteor users collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I Basically have this, which is working fine:

```
Ideas = new Mongo.Collection('ideas', {_driver: companyDb});
```

CompanyDb above is defined as:

```
companyDbString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/demo';
companyDb = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(companyDbString);
```

However, how would i change the driver for the Meteor users collection. I've tried this:

```
Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection('users', {_driver: companyDb});
```

But it gives the expected 'Error: There is already a collection named "users"' error.

I know this sounds like a strange use case, but 'companyDb' changes as the subdomain changes in my application. So I basically need a separate mongo database per sub domain

Comment: I wasn't even aware that you could do this actually.  Perhaps a silly question, but did you check if the `users` collection exists in that database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
AnotherUsersCollection = new Mongo.Collection(“users”, { _driver: companyDb });
```

or

```
var remote = 'mongoURL';
database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver(remote);

You can perform database operations with your database object, like so.

database.mongo.findOne('users', "selector_object")

An example might be

database.mongo.findOne('users', {emails : {$elemMatch : {address : "email_string"} } } )
```

courtsey Dan crescimano
https://forums.meteor.com/t/remote-database-has-the-same-collection-name/7157/3

Comment: Yeah this does seem like the only solution for now, albeit a bit of a mission to implement in terms of forgotten password etc. I'm gonna see if I can fork the accounts package to allow for this instead. Will post a link here when I'm done